# What may be some effective dynamic qr code generators for digital or printing projects?

Tags: branding, marketing, barcodes

What may be some effective dynamic QR code generators for digital or printing projects?  I learned there may be two types of QR codes: static or dynamic to help understand the audience that is viewing the work.

Comment: If you have a new question, make a new post for it. Please don't edit an old post to ask the new question.

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic quick response codes are commercial services. The paid middleman maintains a server which is accessed at first by the person who scans your code. The server redirects him to the actual web site. You have uploaded its URL to the service. The middleman collects statistics and does other activities you have subscribed. He may have a substantial amount of collected and purchased information and tools (=profiles of the people and profile based customized advertising engines) which may be very useful in maximizing your profits - or at least so he will say.

You must purchase the code images from the service provider. The codes work only as long as you keep paying the service. The starting price may be just a round zero today, but do not think it's still the same if your codes become popular (=you are hooked). It's not a charity, it's a business which is founded to collect money.

So, you essentially ask a recommendation for a commercial service provider. I'm afraid this site removes such recommendations quite soon.

Comment: Agree. The best option would be to make a QR directly to the target URL and install whatever analytics we need.

Comment: Links to services you are unaffiliated with (or disclose any affiliation) are fine provided they *actually answer* the question. I think this is a good answer and a link, or a couple links, to such services would be fine. But.. Just my opinion and I'm not a moderator.